# Domain\Administrator can't remote w RDC, cant logon in person, when disconnected from network logs on using previous Password?

Tags: windows-server-2008, login

Server 2008 Domain\Administrator couldnt remote w RDC, now cant logon even in person?

I've found bunch of threads online around having to change some settings on the Server for the Remote to work.

I put it off until I was able to go through the details and apply it. Wierdly, today after I logged into the Server locally "SEVERAL TIMES" as during Power/ Screen Saving mode it auto locks.

For some wierd reason in the evening I was unable to log in even Locally!

What is this new Bug?

1. How do I get in for Starters? Its a locked screen
2. Once in how do I fix this weird BUG and
3. Fix the Remote RDC thing

PS: This is not the DC and even when I change the PW for Domain\Administrator on DC and try it again I get similar issue.

Its as if WRONG passwords are denied Immediately, and the CORRECT Password feels like it will work and in a short time it denies, maybe after short delay. So, what is it doing?

PS: Let me clarify - I am not trying to access it using the LOCAL\Administrator.

I ought to change Local to Physical - I tried Remotely and Physical direct DOMAIN\Administrator was working. Now even DOMAIN\Admin is giving the same issue.

Updated Information:

So initially I was unable to log on. I thought maybe it was trying to authenticate against the DC so lets unplug and try.

Now, I unplugged the machine and I can log on - And the wierd part is I logged in using the OLDER PASSWORD.

i.e. Yesterday on DC DOMAIN\Admin - I changed password to Pass2

Despite the Server being connected to network (& pingable on it) it would not LOG on using Pass1 or Pass2 when connected.

When disconnected from network I logged on using Pass2.

PS: I also thought maybe the DNS on Server was wrong so maybe it was trying to auth against wrong DC IP etc. But I checked and its got all correct IPs for DNS etc.

Answer (score -1):

This might be because of clocks desync.
Try loging in with cable unplugged to your server and check if clock is showing correct time. Also check clock on your DC.